# Haskell ghci do not print value

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghci

I just learn haskell recently.

I write this code in *.hs file, and run ghci in emacs.

```
climbS :: (Fractional a, Enum a, Num a, Integral a) => a -> a
climbS nn = sum [n | n <- [1..(div nn 2)]]
```

I put code below in ghci, and get the type of `climbS`

```
λ> climbS 3
climbS 3 :: (Integral a, Fractional a) => a
```

but if I put expression directly, I get the return that I purposed get

```
λ> let nn = 4 in sum [n | n <- [1..(div nn 2)]]
3
```

How does it happen and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: That's odd, I can't reproduce that behavior. The first entry gives me an ambiguity error (are you sure you typed `climbS 3` and not `:t climbS 3`?), and the second entry gives me a scoping error (are you sure you typed `sum [n | n <- [1..(div nn 2)]]` and not `sum [n | n <- [1..(div 5 2)]` or similar?). Do you have anything fun in a `.ghci` file? What version of GHC do you have?

Comment: I am sure that I type `climbS 3` but `:t climbS 3`. I use ghci drectly in shell instead of in emacs `haskell-mode`, and everything is fine now. I think it is `haskell-mode` issues but not ghci's. Thank you

Comment: Submit this problem to `haskell-mode` on github. [link](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/1446)